# Match multiple object property values on AngularJS typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to get an [Angular Bootstrap UI typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) to match against multiple properties. If i have an array of objects like this:

```
{
    "city":"New York",
    "region":"NY",
    "country":"USA"
},
{
    "city":"London",
    "region":"England",
    "country":"UK"
}
```

Can typeahead match any of the 3 properties (city, region, country ) and if it does, return all as a string in the results dropdown.

If a user types **"NY"** it should return and display

```
New York, NY, USA
```

And if a user instead types **"Lon"** it should return and display

```
London, England, UK
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to do what this and what might be the best approach?

Note: The typeahead is set to match against leading characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. define model**

```
$scope.model.addresses = [
    {"city":"New York","region":"NY","country":"USA"},
    {"city":"London","region":"England", "country":"UK"}
];
```

**2. define custom filter function**

```
$scope.findAddress = function(keyword) {
   return $filter('filter')($scope.model.addresses , {'$': keyword});
}
```

'$' - means find in all properties

**3. and try to use in this way**

```
<input typeahead="address for address in findAddress($viewValue)"/>
```